# Lost permission for sudo in OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, sudo, chmod, osx-elcapitan

I'm new to using OSX (using El Capitan 10.11.3) and while trying to change permissions on a file using sudo, I accidentally corrupted it. Now whenever, I try to use sudo to install anything globally, I'm getting the following error message.

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Is there any way to solve it?

I'm also unable to even view the /etc folder

> bash: cd: /etc: Permission denied

When I checked permissions on /etc folder, they are as follows

```
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel   etc -> private/etc
```

Comment: Are you admin user?  What did you get when typed `csrutil status` in bash?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue and in my case the permissions of the root folder got corrupted. What people overlook is that `/` is in fact also a real, normal directory and just like every directory it has ownership and permissions. Ownership should be `root:wheel` and permission should be `755` (that's `rwxr-xr-x`).

The easiest way to restore both was starting `Script Editor` and then typing and running that script:

```
do shell script "/usr/sbin/chown root:wheel /" with administrator privileges
do shell script "/bin/chmod 755 /" with administrator privileges
```

You are prompted for amdin password and then `chown` and `chmod` come to the rescue. After that `sudo` was working again.

Comment: Thanks, this resolution worked well for me. Clever fix, uses Apples internal method of elevating to fix. Unsure why this happened in the first place, permissions were 705 for some reason. macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Comment: Should something happen after running that script on Script Editor? I enter the password, hit OK and nothing happens. I can see it "Running" for a split second, but I still can't chown or chmod or sudo and I get the same errors (no valid sudoers)

Comment: @zok Wrong ownership or file permissions of the root folder are only one cause of the problem, but they are not the only possible cause. Have you checked that your ownership and permissions of root are really wrong? As if they aren't, of course running that script won't fix anything for you. And "no valid sudoers" can as well mean that your sudoers file is indeed corrupt (contains garbage) or maybe got deleted. Have you checked that the file is even there? You don't need root permissions to check that.

Comment: Perfect, fixed sudo for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

[Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless)](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/)

1. Reboot the Mac and hold down Command + R keys simultaneously after you hear the startup chime, this will boot OS X into Recovery Mode
2. When the “OS X Utilities” screen appears, pull down the ‘Utilities’ menu at the top of the screen instead, and choose “Terminal”
3. Type the following command into the terminal then hit return:

   csrutil disable; reboot
4. You’ll see a message saying that System Integrity Protection has been disabled and the Mac needs to restart for changes to take effect, and the Mac will then reboot itself automatically, just let it boot up as normal

Comment: This is a work computer. So,  I believe I'm not the system admin.

I got the following message when I ran csrutil status

System Integrity Protection status: enabled.

Is it ok to disable it?

Comment: Can I disable it as non-admin or does an admin have to do it?

Also, I work in the health industry. Does disabling this cause any security concerns?

Comment: For developers, System Integrity Protection is a nightmare :).

Comment: I tried entering Recovery Mode but it seems I need root password to login to recovery mode

Comment: So you may contact your system admin to mention this issue.